# Rendering list of forms in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a basic personality test in Django as a proof-of-concept at work.  I'm new to Django (and python in general), coming at it from a C# .NET background.

I am trying to make a list of form objects (populated with information pulled from question objects stored in the database), then display them in the HTML.

This is only partly working; I can render the form attributes individually in a for loop (by calling, for example, question.pk) but nothing renders with the standard Django {{ form }} tag, and trying to submit the list of forms breaks the whole thing.

I'm pretty sure it's an issue with handling a bunch of form objects populated inside one larger html , but I'm not sure how to go about resolving it.

I've done some research into formsets, but I can't find any way to pre-populate the form items with information from the database.

Thanks in advance!

DISCQuestionForm in forms.py:

```py
class DISCQuestionForm(forms.Form):
    # create new form object from database question object
    def __init__(
            self,
            pk,
            disc_query,
            dom_answer,
            infl_answer,
            stead_answer,
            con_answer,
            ):
        super().__init__()
        self.pk = pk
        self.disc_query = disc_query
        self.dom_answer = dom_answer
        self.infl_answer = infl_answer
        self.stead_answer = stead_answer
        self.con_answer = con_answer
        self.disc_response = forms.DecimalField(
            max_value=4,
            widget=forms.NumberInput
            )
```

disc_create method in views.py

```py
# Create a new DISC assessment for current user
def disc_create(request, pk):
    profile = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user = int(profile.pk)
    name = profile.name
    rawquestionset = DISCQuestion.objects.all()

    discformset = []
    for item in rawquestionset:
        question = DISCQuestionForm(
            pk=item.pk,
            disc_query=item.disc_query,
            dom_answer=item.dom_answer,
            infl_answer=item.infl_answer,
            stead_answer=item.stead_answer,
            con_answer=item.con_answer,
        )
        discformset.append(question)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        questionset = discformset[request.POST]
        if questionset.is_valid():
            dom = 0
            infl = 0
            stead = 0
            con = 0

            for discquestion in questionset:
                if discquestion.disc_response == discquestion.dom_answer:
                    dom += 1
                if discquestion.disc_response == discquestion.infl_answer:
                    infl += 1
                if discquestion.disc_response == discquestion.stead_answer:
                    stead += 1
                if discquestion.disc_response == discquestion.con_answer:
                    con += 1

            disctest = DISCTest(
                user=user,
                name=name,
                dom=dom,
                infl=infl,
                stead=stead,
                con=con,
            )
            disctest.save()
    else:
        questionset = discformset

    context = {
        "pk": user,
        "name": name,
        "discquestionset": questionset
    }

    return render(request, "disc_create.html", context)
```

DISCTest and DISCQuestion models in models.py:

```py
class DISCTest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = user.name
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dom = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    infl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    stead = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    con = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)


class DISCQuestion(models.Model):
    disc_query = models.TextField()
    disc_response = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=0, null=True)
    dom_answer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=0)
    infl_answer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=0)
    stead_answer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=0)
    con_answer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=0)
```

and finally disc_create.html in templates:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>Take your DISC assessment</h1>
    <hr>
    <h3>Insert instructions here</h3>
    <hr>
    <form action="/assessment/create/{{pk}}/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            {% for question in discquestionset %}
                <p>{{question.pk}}</p>
                <p>{{ question.disc_query }}</p>
                {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DiscQuestionForm` has no fields. `disc_response` is defined as an attribute of the form but for Django it isn't a field because it isn't added to `self.fields`. And `form` isn't defined in your template in your for loop, only `question` (which is the form) so `{{ question }}` would print the form if it had any fields.

But then the problem is that each of your `question` form fields would all have the same "name" attributes because they are not prefixed to make them unique.

You should read [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) carefully to understand `ModelForm` and `modelformset`. Basically you need:

```
class DISCQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DISCQuestion

    def __init__(...):
        ...
```

Use the `modelformset_factory` to create a proper `ModelFormSet` that you can initialise with the `request.POST` when submitted.

```
DISCQuestionFormSet = modelformset_factory(DISCQuestionForm, form = DISCQuestionForm)  # note DISCQuestionForm not needed if you don't customise anything in your form.
```

and in your view:

```
formset = DISCQuestFormSet(request.POST or None)
```

then in your template you can loop through the forms in the formset:

```
{% for form in formset %}{{ form }}{% endfor %}
```